# Clear IDE analysis warning `Cannot find variable` in scss file for variables used within a mixin @content directive?

Tags: sass, phpstorm

I'm cleaning up all my analysis warnings in my `theme.scss` file. Though I am not sure how to clear this one...

I have a `@mixin` called `accent-colors` which simply loops through a sass map of colours by key/value, and wraps the `@content` directive input with a `.accent-#{$key}` parent class selector.

```scss
@mixin accent-colors {
  @each $key, $value in $accent-colors {
    $accent-name: $key !global;
    $accent-color: $value !global;
    .accent-#{$key} & {
      @content
    }
  }
}
```

This `@mixin accent-colors` is located in a separate file `_mixins.scss` which is imported into `theme.scss` using `@import "mixins"`.

The `@content` directive allows variables to be passed into this via `@include accent-colors { }`

Here is an example...

```scss
.button
  @include accent-colors {
    color: $accent-color;
  }
}
```

The above sass code works fine, but I get this analysis warning in my IDE ([phpstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)) in the `theme.scss` file...

[image]

Is there a way to some how suppress this IDE analysis warning in my `theme.scss` file?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can suppress it with comment:

```
.button {
  //noinspection SassScssUnresolvedVariable
  @include accent-colors {
    color: $accent-color;
  }
}
```

see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-in-editor